# Android, calling the browser from javascript inside a WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I try to call the browser of my device loading a page inside a WebView that contains:

```
window.open(
  'http://www.stackoverflow',
  '_blank'.
);
```

**I need to do this from the html that is loaded into the WebView**

but i have no success, any idea!?

Comment: you can run javascript on webview like this 

 view.loadUrl("javascript: $('.CARS_panelTitle').css('display','none')");

using Webclient

Answer (score 2):

There are several things you need to do in your app:

1. Use `setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically` as @ajpolt says. This will allow `window.open` to not fail.
2. Enable `setSupportMultipleWindows`. This makes WebView to actually attempt opening a new window. Otherwise, it will be opening the URL in the same WebView.
3. Hook up to `WebChromeClient.onCreateWindow` callback and create a new `WebView` instance there. For this new instance, you need to set `WebViewClient` that will launch the intent from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`.

Below is sample code:

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());
```

And this is the `ChromeClient`:

```
class ChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
        WebView tempWebView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
        tempWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                browserIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                return true;
            }
        });
        WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
        transport.setWebView(tempWebView);
        resultMsg.sendToTarget();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing a setting on your webview.

Try using [setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(boolean)) in your settings, like this:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```